# Wrapped Exception when searching user from Alfresco share admin console

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Am getting the following error when searching an user from admin console.

```
00060029 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 00060038 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/enterprise/webscripts/org/alfresco/enterprise/repository/person/people-enterprise.get.js': pageSize must be greater than zero.
```

Alfresco version : 4.2.6

User : admin

[image]

Error from log

```
[2017-01-06 16:02:55,902] ERROR org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime  - Exception from executeScript - redirecting to status template error: 00060029 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 00060038 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/enterprise/webscripts/org/alfresco/enterprise/repository/person/people-enterprise.get.js': pageSize must be greater than zero.
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 00060029 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 00060038 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/enterprise/webscripts/org/alfresco/enterprise/repository/person/people-enterprise.get.js': pageSize must be greater than zero.
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:171)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:464)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:457)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:539)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:607)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScriptInternal(RepositoryContainer.java:381)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:262)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:378)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
```

Can anyone please tell me why am I getting this error and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Have you made any changes directly to any of the files Alfresco ships, especially JavaScript files?

Comment: @JeffPotts thanks for the reply... But i haven't changed any of the out of box files.

Comment: You are running Enterprise Edition. Have you tried contacting support?

Comment: @JeffPotts : My team mate contacted the Alfresco support and the issue is solved.  In-order to change the search limit, we have added config tag for condition="Search"  in share-config-custom.xml with replace="true" and we haven't mentioned <max-users-search-results>, because of which search was not working properly. Thanks for the support. :)